# How to correctly organize array of property objects from initialvalues

Tags: reactjs, formik

I am using Formik in React and need to update data in form and a FieldArray

```
<Formik
    enableReinitialize={true} initialValues={{ title: '', somelocations: [{location: locationEntity.locations && locationEntity.locations.map(e => e.id)}] ...

<FieldArray
    name="somelocations"
    render={arrayHelpers => (
    ...
    {values.locations && values.locations.length > 0 ? (
    values.locations.map((location, index) => (
    <div key={index}>
    ...
    <div className="location-field-value form-group"><Field type="text" placeholder="https://some.com" required name={`somelocations.${index}.location`} /></span></div>
    ...
    />
```

As a result, I get values from initial values, but they are not organized correctly. Not each in a separate input, but all together separated by commas

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

Every works fine if i delete property of the 'somelocation' array -> location
{`somelocations.${index}.location`}

How to correctly organize array of objects from initialvalues for array property?

Comment: Can you add a reproducible example in https://codesandbox.io/?

Answer (score 0):

Incorrect initialValue on my side. Right way

```
initialValues={{ title: '', somelocations: locationEntity.locations}}
```